# Include JSX attributes in multiple html elements

Tags: typescript, jsx

I have some JSX attributes that I want to add to multiple other elements.

Example attribtes that I need to be included:

```
class?: string;
id?: string;
style?: string;
```

Example elements:

```
namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        element1: { att1: string; }
        element2: { att2: string; }
        element3: { att3: string; }
    }
}
```

What it should behave like:

```
namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        element1: { att1: string; class?: string; id?: string; style?: string; }
        element2: { att2: string; class?: string; id?: string; style?: string; }
        element3: { att3: string; class?: string; id?: string; style?: string; }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without the need of duplicate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, with the `|` operator you can merge two interfaces.

This way you can define a interface for all base attributes (e.g. class, id, style) and merge it with the specific attribute interfaces (e.g. { att1: string; } ).

So here is my solution as code:

```
namespace JSX {
    interface BaseAttributes {
        class?: string;
        id?: string;
        style?: string;
    }
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        element1: BaseAttributes | { att1: string; }
        element2: BaseAttributes | { att2: string; }
        element3: BaseAttributes | { att3: string; }
    }
}
```